# How to reference and compute other parts of Javascript object?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to calculate basic volume from the l, w, h attributes of this object `cube`, which is an object within `item`.

```js
var item = new Object();
    
item["cube"] = {
    dimensions: [1.00,2.00,1.50, "in"], // l, w, h, unit (inches)
    volume: (this.dimensions[0] * this.dimensions[1] * this.dimensions[2]) // V = l * w * h
};

alert( item["cube"].volume + item["cube"].dimensions[3] ); // Volume + unit (inches)
```

I have also tried not using `this` when calculating volume, instead, specifying the exact part of the object: `item["cube"][dimensions][0] * item["cube"][dimensions][1] * item["cube"][dimensions][2]`.

The goal is to get the alert `3.00in` or `3in`. Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong and if this could even work? Am I allowed to put functions in objects?

Edit: added actual function:

```js
var item = new Object();

function calcVolume (l,w,h) {
 return l * w * h;
};

item["cube"] = {
    dimensions: [1.00,2.00,1.50, "in"], // l, w, h, unit (inches)
    volume: calcVolume(this.dimensions[0],this.dimensions[1],this.dimensions[2]) // V = l * w * h
};

alert( item["cube"].volume + item["cube"].dimensions[3] ); // Volume + unit (inches)
```

Comment: You haven't tried to put a function into an object.

Comment: There's no such thing as a dictionary in Javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this` in a function:

```js
var item = {
  "cube": {
    dimensions: [1.00, 2.00, 1.50, "in"],
    volume: function () { return this.dimensions[0] * this.dimensions[1] * this.dimensions[2]; }
  }
};

alert( item["cube"].volume() + item["cube"].dimensions[3] );
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [`getter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) for this.

```js
var item = new Object();
function calcVolume (l,w,h) { return l * w * h;};

item["cube"] = {
    dimensions: [1.00,2.00,1.50, "in"], // l, w, h, unit (inches)
    get volume() { return calcVolume(this.dimensions[0],this.dimensions[1],this.dimensions[2]) }
};

alert( item["cube"].volume + item["cube"].dimensions[3] ); // Volume + unit (inches)
```

Although I think this would be a great example for [ES6 Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

```js
class Cube {
  constructor(l, w, h, unit) {
    this.l = l;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.unit = unit || "in";
  }
  get volume() { return this.l * this.w * this.h };
  get volumeAsString() { return this.volume + this.unit };
}

var c = new Cube(1.00, 2.00, 1.50);
console.log(c.volumeAsString);
```

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of `getter`s. This seems much more streamlined.